# Form elements into $_POST arrays

Tags: html, forms

I'm probably being stupid, because its Friday afternoon, but I just can't work this out.

What I want is to have a form where users can add infinite "records". To do this they click an "add record" button. This runs javascript which adds a new row (tr) to a table within the `<form>`.

This new row has three input fields.

What I want is for this to be sent to the post variable in a format such as (but not exact if it can't be done, but there's a better way):

```
$_POST['record'] = array(
    array(
        "input1" => "value",
        "input2" => "value",
        "input3" => "value"
    ),
    array(
        "input1" => "value",
        "input2" => "value",
        "input3" => "value"
    ),
    array(
        "input1" => "value",
        "input2" => "value",
        "input3" => "value"
    ),
);
```

I know you can get arrays by using the name like so:

```
<input type="text" name="record[]" />
```

But this is only 1 input element. Is there any way to get a structure like above with 3 elements?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily get what you're looking for exactly, but you can use `name="record[input1][]"` (and `input2` etc.) and the result is:

```
$_POST['record'] = array(
    "input1"=>array(
        "value", "value", "value"
    ),
    "input2"=>array(
        "value", "value", "value"
    ),
    "input3"=>array(
        "value", "value", "value"
    )
);
```

You could then transform it into your desired format like so:

```
$out = Array();
foreach(array_keys($_POST['record']['input1']) as $i) {
    foreach($_POST['record'] as $k=>$v) {
        $out[$i][$k] = $v[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems like the best way to do it

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) Can I guarantee the order of the fields? Is it the order in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, the fields are sent in the order they appear in the HTML form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. using `name=record[]`. You'll get something like

```
$_POST['record'] = array(
    "record" =>  array(
        "value",
        "value",
        "value"
    ),
    "field2" =>  array(
        "value",
        "value",
        "value"
    ),
    "field3" =>  array(
        "value",
        "value",
        "value"
     )
);
```

So to get each row, you'd use

```
$cnt = count( $theArray['record'] );
for ($x=0; $x<$cnt; $x++){
    echo $theArray['record'][$x];
    echo $theArray['field2'][$x];
    echo $theArray['field3'][$x];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks... this seems like the only way to do what I need. Can I guarantee the order of the fields in the array? Is it the order they are in my HTML? Thanks

Comment: They will be in the same order they are in within the HTML. If you need them in a certain order, you'd need to display them that way or manually edit the results.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried --

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="record['set1'][]" />
<input type="text" name="record['set1'][]" />
<input type="text" name="record['set1'][]" />
<input type="text" name="record['set2'][]" />
<input type="text" name="record['set2'][]" />
<input type="text" name="record['set2'][]" />
<input type="text" name="record['set3'][]" />
<input type="text" name="record['set3'][]" />
<input type="text" name="record['set3'][]" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Output --

```
Array
(
    [record] => Array
        (
            ['set1'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            ['set2'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                )

            ['set3'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 7
                    [1] => 8
                    [2] => 9
                )

        )

)
```

Is this how you wanted it?

Comment: I can work with this I guess. What I wanted was the other way around: `<input name="record[]['input1']" /><input name="record[]['input2']" />` but with that you'll get `record[0]['input1']` and `record[1]['input2']`. :/ I can just do it manually. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more clearly for you,

```
$record = array();
foreach($_POST['record'] as $val){
   $record[] = $val;
}
print_r($record);
```